# Set imap depending on filetype

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I'm using the [xml](https://github.com/othree/xml.vim) and [omnicppcompl](https://github.com/vim-scripts/OmniCppComplete) plugins for Vim, and making use of two insert mappings these plugins define for the '>' key. My problem is that while the **omnicppcompl** plugin will happily `imap` the '>' key when I enter a buffer of `filetype` **cpp** or **c**, but when it does, the **xml** plugin's `imap` of the '>' key will no longer work, as it wont remap itself when I enter a buffer of filetype **xml**. This causes me to be unable to further use the functionality the mapping provides when I edit xml files, which is to automatically write a closing tag (the **omnicppcompl** map stays though).

What I'm looking for is that these two mappings are available in their respective `filetype`, and I believe the issue lies in the **xml** plugin not remapping itself the way **omnicppcompl** can. I tried writing quick `autocmd`'s in my .vimrc to manually remap the '>' key, but the **xml** plugin `imap`'s to a local function in its script with the `<SID>` bit.

Does anyone know how I can work around this? Is there a way to force the **xml** plugin to re-run its mapping? I don't know very much about vim scripting and how plugins operate, but is it because the **xml** plugin has no `autoload` scripts?

For reference, the **xml** plugin maps the '>' key on **line 1485** of `ftplugin/xml.vim`, and the **omnicppcompl** plugin maps the '>' key on **line 40** of `autoload/omni/cpp/complete.vim`

I would greatly appreciate any help and suggestions for how to fix/workaround this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just gave a quick look at those two files and, from what I gather, it looks like the mapping is done correctly in the `xml` plugin:

```
inoremap <silent> <buffer> > ><Esc>:call <SID>CloseTagFun()<Cr>
```

while it is done incorrectly in the `omnicppcomplete` plugin:

```
inoremap <expr> > omni#cpp#maycomplete#Arrow()
```

When doing that kind of mapping, plugin authors should try to restrict their scope as much as possible: filetype-specific mappings should be buffer-local, using `<buffer>` as in the first example.

As it stands, depending on how you loaded your files, the `cpp` mapping may take precedence over the `xml` mapping because it seems to be too broadly applied to the whole Vim instance instead of `cpp` buffers.

Additionally, the `omnicppcomplete` plugin doesn't use `ftplugin` which is kind of the norm for filetype-specific stuff.

As an immediate solution, I suggest you to add `<buffer>` to the `cpp` mapping and, if that works, try to contact the author and convince him/her to modify the plugin upstream.

```
inoremap <buffer> <expr> > omni#cpp#maycomplete#Arrow()
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll try to contact the original author, and for now I've added `buffer` to that mapping line. We'll see how that goes I guess :)

Comment: Just to be sure, that's `<buffer>` not `buffer`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I used. I should have been more specific :p